# Can I check whether an address is in shared memory?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I want to write the following CUDA function:

```
void foo(int* a, size_t n)
{
     if ( /* MAGIC 1 */ ) {
         // a is known to be in shared memory, 
         // so use it directly
     }
     else {
         // make a copy of a in shared memory
         // and use the copy
     }
 }
```

On the host side, we have a slightly-related facility in the form of [cudaPointerGetAttributes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__UNIFIED.html#group__CUDART__UNIFIED_1gd89830e17d399c064a2f3c3fa8bb4390), which can tell us whether or not a pointer is to device memory or host memory; perhaps there's some way to distinguish pointers in device code as well, and perhaps it can also discern shared from global pointers. Alternatively, and perhaps even better - maybe there's a compile-time mechanism to do that, since, after all, the device functions are only compiled into kernels and are not freestanding, so `nvcc` can often know whether they're used with shared memory or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>This is a generalization of @tera's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42526590/1593077).</sub>

Use `is_in_shared_memory()` from the following code, which defines similar functions for all possible on-device memory spaces:

```
#ifndef STRINGIFY
#define STRINGIFY(_q) #_q
#endif

#define IS_IN_MEMORY_SPACE(_which_space) \
__forceinline__ __device__ int is_in_ ## _which_space ## _memory (const void *ptr) \
{ \
    int result; \
    asm ("{" \
        ".reg .pred p;\n\t" \
        "isspacep." STRINGIFY(_which_space) " p, %1;\n\t" \
        "selp.b32 %0, 1, 0, p;\n\t" \
        "}" \
        : "=r"(result) : "l"(ptr)); \
    return result; \
}

IS_IN_MEMORY_SPACE(const)
IS_IN_MEMORY_SPACE(global)
IS_IN_MEMORY_SPACE(local)
IS_IN_MEMORY_SPACE(shared)

#undef IS_IN_MEMORY_SPACE
```

If you're building 32-bit code, replace the `"l"` constraint (a 64-bit address) with `"r"`.

Comment: @tera: Fankly - only compiled it, I'm not at a machine with a GPU right this second...

Comment: @tera: You're right, it won't work. I will do something else though.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`isspacep` PTX instruction](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#data-movement-and-conversion-instructions-isspacep) via a bit of inline "assembly":

```
// First, a pointer-size-related definition, in case
// this code is being compiled in 32-bit rather than 
// 64-bit mode; if you know the code is always 64-bit
// you can just use the "l"

#if defined(_WIN64) || defined(__LP64__)
# define PTR_CONSTRAINT "l"
#else
# define PTR_CONSTRAINT "r"
#endif

__device__ int isShared(void *ptr)
{
    int res;
    asm("{"
        ".reg .pred p;\n\t"
        "isspacep.shared p, %1;\n\t"
        "selp.b32 %0, 1, 0, p;\n\t"
        "}" :
        "=r"(res): PTR_CONSTRAINT(ptr));
    return res;
}
```

so your example becomes

```
__device__ void foo(int* a, size_t n)
{
     if (isShared(a)) {
         // a is known to be in shared memory, 
         // so use it directly
     } else {
         // make a copy of a in shared memory
         // and use the copy
     }
}
```

Comment: Great :-) Can you explain why I need that extra Win64-specific voodoo at the beginning? Also, the PTX guide says we have "generic" memory addresses and, supposedly, space-specific addresses. How does that bear on your answer?

Comment: I added that "voodoo" just in case anyone tries to compile in 32 bit mode. If you know your code is always 64 bits, you can just use the `"l"` constraint for the pointer directly.

Comment: Also, why do you need the selp, if `p` already gets either a 0 or a 1? Can't the result register be used directly as a predicate register?

Comment: Yes, it could be used directly in PTX. But I am not aware of a method to pass a predicate back to the C compiler, so we get the overhead of another conversion instruction and have to hope that ptxas will be able to optimize it out again.